# KVM with dual output for extended desktop

Tags: kvm

I'm having trouble finding a solution for setting up a switch for three laptops to two monitors. I'd need a KVM that matches the following criteria:

- 3 inputs for the laptops
- 2 outputs to two monitors supporting extended monitor or multiple display (not mirrored), or some splitting solution
- Doesn't break the bank

Extra details:
3 laptops will be used as sources, 2 laptops have both VGA and HDMI out, 1 laptop only has HDMI out, and all laptops have several USB slots.

I have looked into an HDMI-to-VGA adapter (or even HDMI-to-DVI in case I want to convert all three to DVI). This seems like a good solution for getting my sources into a 4-port KVM.

The real problem I'm running into is the output. I have a requirement to output the source onto two monitors for an extended monitor (so long as it isn't mirrored display which would be useless to my client). I haven't seen a KVM that has dual output from the console but only 1 input from each computer. I considered a DVI or VGA Y-splitter and read reviews that this only allows for mirrored displays. Any ideas? And if someone could confirm the behavior of Y-splitters, that could solve my problem easily.

Honestly, a KVM would be great, but thinking outside of the box would be fine. I have considered RDC as a possible solution to this, but I don't believe my client is technical enough to buy into it.

Answer (score 1):

**Software-Solution**
This might not be the same type of product you are seeking however it is a full-proof approach to software KVM(A). You could try Synergy or one of it's many alternatives that handle KVM at the network level. I've used Synergy for many years on my dev box with a configuration of two laptops, two towers, and a CCTV which runs Ubuntu desktop. The only downside is that Synergy is no longer a free approach. It seems Symless is going through some growing pains as they ramp up their new company.

**Source:** https://symless.com/synergy

**Hardware Solution**
If you are unable to use Synergy, StarTech makes a nice two port solution. I'm not quite sure about your budget since you stated "doesn't break the bank", but this one will run you $292.00 USD. At any rate shop around on NewEgg before making a KVM purchase, and beware of the triplite generics.

Note: as far as output goes, you can always find a converter from DVI to HDMI vice versa, and even VGA to DVI/HDMI.

**Source:** [https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707420&cm_re=kvm_switch_2_monitors_2_computers-*-17-707-420-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707420&cm_re=kvm_switch_2_monitors_2_computers-_-17-707-420-_-Product)

Comment: Really? This question was asked two years ago, and there was a more relevant question more recently than that. Please check first.

Comment: Irrelevant. I answered a question with a logical response, regardless of the stale state.

Comment: Irrelevant. The OP is not likely to mark the question as answered as he has probably solved it by now.

Comment: @EdwardNunn Every question should have an answer. There are even [badges](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) for answering old questions.

Comment: @Cfinley OK, ill accept adjustment, but given the nature of this StackExchange site, I would have thought that it would be somewhat useless to do so.

Comment: @EdwardNunn Some hardware do not really change over the years, like keyboard, mice, KVMs, UPSs, etc. Plus you never know when an answer will help out someone other than OP.

Comment: Isn't there a chip one could use to build a KVM the same way one can build an Ethernet switch or a USB hub?

Just for clarification, this is a completely selfish (as in "enlightened self-interest") comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/any-chips-for-building-a-kvm